# .htaccess to redirect to 404 (Not Found) message on unauthorized folder access

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to display a 404 (Not found) message, when the user tries to access unauthorized directory. I do not want to use Forbidden pages. I have tried with below code, but it does not work.

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/htaccess/.*$
```

Any idea on what might be going wrong?

Comment: Why do you not want to use forbidden pages?

Comment: @Dan I think to make the directory invisible.

Comment: @rekire ya u r correct. i can make every folder invincible by using RedirectMatch 404 / but i have to put htaccess in every folder. any way to affect all child directory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try adding the following to your htaccess file

```
#if the URI starts with htaccess, return a 404
RewriteRule ^htaccess/ - [R=404,L,NC]
```

**Edit**

> eg system/function,system/class,...

If you have a lot of folders then use a RewriteCond as below as it is easier to read than multiple folders in a single RewriteRule or multiple RewriteRules, which duplicate the 404 piece

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^htaccess/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system/function/ [NC,OR]
#just make sure the last rule does  NOT have an OR
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system/class/ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [R=404,L,NC]
```

Comment: i got whole branch of folder, for eg system/function,system/class, if user try to access these folder by uri, just show them 404 page. do i nid to write a htaccess in every folder?

Comment: That is a really nice solution +1

Answer (score 0):

R=404 is not a valid R value, it must be within the 300-399 range or will be ignored. It's better to simply redirect to a non-existant url that is not blocked by other rules, this will trigger your errordocument.